# pulldown menu option parent-child

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, flask, jinja2

**[Environment]**

Flask Web application, Python 3.7, MySql

**[What I would like to do]**

I have a modal form triggered by a button.
Inside the modal there are several input fields. Among them, 2 pulldown menus.
Pulldown menu A contains categories, while Pulldown menu B subcategories.

When a category is selected from Pulldown menu A, I would like to change the option of Pulldown menu B accordingly. (For example, if A is 1, I want B to display only 1a,1b,1c. Otherwise, if A is 2, B should display only 2a,2b,2c)

Also, data are acquired from database as a list.
DB structure should be something like this:

#Category#

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

#Subcategory#

| ID | Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1a |
| 2 | 1 | 1b |
| 3 | 1 | 1c |

Pulldown menu A is displaying options correctly. (code below)
I have problem with Pulldown menu B. (displaying all subcategories regardless of selected category)

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" name="bal-edit-category" required>
        <option disabled selected value> {{ row.category }} </option>
        {% for category in category %}
        <option value="{{ category.category }}">{{ category.category }} 
        </option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Python Flask

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)    
cursor.execute('SELECT category FROM category')
category = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template('test.html', category=category)
```

Any comments or suggestions will be very appreciated.

Comment: If there are not too many subcategories, then you can generate a javascript array with category - subcategory pairs and use that to show your options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to thank Shadow for the hint.
After a lot of trouble I was finally able to obtain the desired result.
Basically, I just wrote a piece of Python code and call it via Ajax. Then a Javascript script will handle changes on pulldowns and displays related contents only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).